# How to prevent a component re-render on a hover event located outside the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, mouseover

I have a behaviour that changes the opacity of an element in the page when I hover a div that wraps a react component. The behaviour works fine. However, I noticed that every time the event fires the wrapped component re-render. I want to avoid that. Is there a way to prevent this?

By the way, I am using React.memo() in the component in question.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Pseudo-code

- Detect if the cursor over a component
- If the hover is confirmed change the opacity of another component without re-render the wrapped component

Code

```
<div
  role="none"
  onMouseEnter={() => {
    setIsShown(cursorOpacity)
  }}
  onMouseLeave={() => {
    setIsShown(1)
  }}
>
  <SectionHeader />
</div>
```

Comment: How do you use `isShown` value (I suppose it's a hook, right?)? Is it a prop for `SectionHeader`? Have you thought to use CSS approach for changing opacity?

Comment: Normally it should no re-render, if I understanded your pseudo-code correctly, take look at here I made an example similar to yours https://codesandbox.io/s/rerender-reactmemo-forked-ijx1q?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @petrichor It is a react hook. How can I use CSS to do that? Is there a way to find all the components wrapped with a certain class and trigger the event only on those? ARZMI Thank you for your example. I am puzzled about how it is working on yours. I need to double-check my code and search for insistencies if I am doing something different. Thank you both.

Comment: Do you pass any props to `SectionHeader`? In case of CSS aproach you can use this selector if you want change child's style when parent hovered `.parent:hover .child { ... }`